# Terminating a Faye client connection

Tags: node.js, faye

I want to terminate a Faye client connection.

Is there command like

```
client.destroy()
```

or something that can terminate connection from the browser?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this,

client.disconnect()

that will disconnect your connection to the faye..
but my problem is, how to connect again..   :(

Comment: To connect again, you just need to re-call the initiate faye procedure